# Comparing count groups/histograms with different bins

Tags: chi-squared-test, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, histogram, model-comparison

I'm looking at clustering techniques for which I have a ground truth.

From the ground truth I can extract the cardinality (size) of clusters and I would like to test how well different methods can predict the true clusterings, and one of the measures I would like to use should quantify how well we can approximate the empirical "distribution" of cluster cardinalities.

Example:

```
True clustering:
Cluster Size | Number of clusters with this size
1 | 4
2 | 12
3 | 3
4 | 9
5 | 1
6 | 1


Predicted clustering:
Cluster Size | Number of clusters with this size
1 | 3
2 | 5
3 | 12
4 | 3
```

My problem comes from the fact that the total number of clusters will be different in the true and predicted clusterings, and the number observed sizes will also be different. AFAIK that means I cannot use something like a two-sample KS test.

How can I compare then the similarity between two "histograms" (with bin size  = 1) that have a different number of observations and bins?